# Can we add a Apple Watch extention to a xamarin forms app (cross platform app)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, apple-watch

Can we add a Apple Watch extention to a xamarin forms app (cross platform app)  ?

I have searched on google and  seen info only on xamarin.ios with Apple Watch but not with xamarin forms cross platform.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes you can, but you must write this in your platfrom specific project. this means the ui and logic must be written in the native code. If you use a mvvm framework you can share some code across platforms.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/

Comment: so then it's Xamarin but not Xamarin.Forms? this answer is very ambiguous

Comment: Yes it is Xamarin but not in Xamarin.Forms, it is in the native way of writing code

Comment: then your answer should start with "NO", instead of "Yes", because the question is about XamarinForms

Comment: Since you still need to use Native code, then it is not Xamarin Forms. Therefore, "No you can not"